# get subprocess to format correctly

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute an ansible-playbook commend in subprocess at the end of a python script, which does 'magic' before kicking off the correct command.

If you are not familiar with ansible-playbook.  The output is normally colorful(green/yellow/red text) and is correctly spaced.

I would be fine if python just kicked off a command and exited if need be.

What I am getting currently is black and white text after the command has completed.

I want to get the normal color outout in real time as if I ran ansible-playbook from the command line.  Is there a way to do this?

my current code is as follows:

```
command = '{0} --flush-cache -f 20 -i {1}/dyn_inv.py --extra-vars @{2}/vars.json {3}'.format(ansible_playbook_loc, script_path, var_path, args.playbook[0])
print command
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
devices = process.communicate()[0].rstrip('\n').split()
print devices
```

Comment: Most applications that display colored output only do so if output is going to a terminal, not a pipe or file. Check if the command has an option to force colored output when not going to a terminal.

Comment: If not, use the [pseudo terminal utilities](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html) to run the `ansible-playbook` command through a pty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible by default will only colorize text when its output is connected to a terminal.  You can force it to use color codes by setting `ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=1` in the environment.  For example:

```
import os
os.environ['ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR'] = '1'
```

You can accomplish the same thing by setting the [force_color](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#force-color) option in your `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks!